# What's the correct usage of "agree some days" vs. "agree on some days"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, ielts

> "However, workers and employers can agree longer holidays".

I have searched online. I also referred to two reference books : the blue book of grammar and grammar rules. I don't see a usage as of the sentence above.

This sentence feels and looks quite odd to me. Shouldn't it be "agree on holidays"?

PS: Full paragraph is quoted from Cambridge IELTS 8 : general reading test A
ISBN : 878-1-107-62613-3

> "Workers who qualify are entitled to no fewer than 4 weeks of paid
>   holiday per year, and public holidays (normally eight days in England
>   and Wales) count towards this. However, workers and employers can
>   agree longer holidays."

Comment: "... agree holidays ..." is Brit (or at least Beeb) usage.  "... agree on holidays ..." would be US usage.

Comment: @HotLicks We have both! :) But you're quite right that we often agree things over here in blighty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that omitting the preposition means something different, and so it really depends what it is intended to mean.

1. If they are agreeing about what days holidays should be, then yes, it needs an extra *on*.
2. However, if it just means that holidays are the only times that they are ever in agreement, then you could use *holidays* adverbially, just as we do with *yesterday* or *Tuesday*.

> They always agree holidays, but workdays they’re back to fighting tooth and nail.
>
> They agreed yesterday, but Tuesday they will surely change their minds again.
>
> They agree Mondays and Tuesdays but argue during the rest of the week.

Comment: Quite tricky, isn't it? at least to me. I am still trying to make sense of it and to see how natural it will feel in verble usage, if I may apply it...

Comment: I disagree (in Std AmE, at least) that *holiday(s)* can be used in this suggested adverbial manner.

Comment: @Hellion People working Sundays and holidays get paid double-time.

Comment: From listening to/reading BBC materials, I've gotten the strong impression that it's at least not unusual for Brits to omit "to" in your first case above.

Comment: @aspiring Omitting the preposition is ungrammatical for sense 1 in American English.

Comment: @tchrist I am not a native Brit and from day 1 I have never used US English but British. But I reckon there are quite a bit of elements that are very British ;)

Comment: @tchrist : I asked [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52208/whats-the-right-word-usage-or-choice-centring-or-centric) in the wrong site, although I intended it for this site. Will you be able to enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Agree [can be used](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/agree) transitively without a preposition: this is typically in the context of formal negotiations, rather than when discussing opinions.

So, you can **agree** a contract, or terms, or a price, or hours, pay, holidays, etc.

To my (British English) ear, at least, to say "workers and employers can **agree on** holidays" might imply "however, workers and employers can agree that holidays are a good thing", whereas the actual meaning is that the dates of holidays are the details which must be agreed by both parties.

You can also **agree to** some of these things, although usually in response to a request. Simply to "agree to holidays" would mean "we agree that they should happen", not the dates the holidays will actually take place. Typically, a worker makes a request for time off and the employer agrees to the request.

As an aside, 5.6 weeks' holiday (including 8 days of public holidays) is now the [legal minimum](https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/entitlement) in the UK. Of course, employees and employers can (and often do) **agree more**.

Comment: There's an adjective that I missed out. I guess that could be one reason I didn't feel a smooth flow. `can agree longer holidays`.

Comment: Either is perfectly acceptable English, but they have different meanings. "We agreed holidays" would be used to say"we agreed what the dates of holidays would be"; "we agreed longer holidays" would be used to say "we agreed a right to longer holidays would be part of the contract"

Answer (score 1):

This usage of *agree*, which takes a direct object instead of a prepositional complement is quite common, especially in British English. If you are taking an IELTS exam then you are quite likely to see it.

Here is the entry for *agree* from Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> 2.1 [with object] Reach agreement about (something) after negotiation:
>
> > '*if they had **agreed a price** the deal would have gone through*'
> >
> > **More example sentences**
> >
> > *The plan involves **agreeing a pay rise** for this year and continuing negotiations over wage increases for the next two years*.
> >
> > *It was agreed that negotiations should take place with both contractors*.
> >
> > *After negotiation, we **agree a set of terms** under which the autopsy will be performed*.

Notice that these sentences do not use the preposition *on*. They take a direct object instead.

Notice as well that *workers and employers can agree holidays* means that they can arrange what holidays workers have by agreement. It does *NOT* mean that workers and employers agree during holiday periods in this text! You need to be clear about this to get a good grade in your IELTS.

Good luck with your exam!

**Reference**: "Agree", verb. Oxford Dictionaries Online. Accessed 19 January 2015.